# How come there is an option for fragment but I can't retrieve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fragment

In ASP.net why is there an option to get the URL fragment (aka. Hash) but I cannot get the fragment from it. `requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Fragment`.

Now I understand that you can't get the fragment because the server never knows about it but I want to know why the option is there with in the `HttpContext` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because HttpContext.Request.Url is of type System.Uri, and that one has a Fragment parameter. When using System.Uri on it's own, it's certainly possible to add/read the fragment, just in this scenario where it's used by ASP.net's runtime, it's not applicable.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you have a real world example of how you would use System.Uri to your advantage with the fragment?

Comment: @brenjt Whenever I would generate URLs server-side to send to the client. Instead of string concatenation, I can split the functions that generate the URL. (e.g., the fragment is generated by a function that determines the action to take, while the host name may depend on the environment, whether or not the client is local or remote. Same for the path, if you run something that allows multiple sites in one application, the path may need to be generated for the current site). Essentially, for routing.

Comment: Okay, I follow you. Would be great for using in conjunction with Backbone.js or similar. Thank you.